# cannot find package error

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to use hector_quadrotor stack to simulate the UAV.  However I met some problems when I roslaunch the file spawn_quadrotor.launch which in the package hector_quadrotor_urdf. This is what I see:

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [odometry_to_tf/odometry_to_tf]: Cannot locate node of type [odometry_to_tf] in package [odometry_to_tf]

I have already executed the command " rosdep install odometry_to_tf " and " rosmake odometry_to_tf " . Also I can find the package odometry_to_tf by typing command roscd.

Thank you very much for your help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30475/cannot-find-package-error/) by [lu weining](https://answers.ros.org/users/1524/lu-weining/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lu weining](https://answers.ros.org/users/1524/lu-weining/) on 2012-03-26**:
I have already use command "rosmake" to install this ROS package , it doesn't work.

**Comment by [lu weining](https://answers.ros.org/users/1524/lu-weining/) on 2012-03-28**:
@Lorenz Thank you for your advice. But it didn't work. I have installed the hector_localication stack, nothing happened.  Do you have any ideas?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-03-29**:
How did you install the stack? Did you install the trunk version? Is it present in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`odometry_to_tf` is not a debian package but a ROS package, so rosdep will not install it. `roslocate info odometry_to_tf` shows the following output:

```
- svn:
    local-name: odometry_to_tf
    uri: http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_localization/odometry_to_tf
```

Install the stack hector_localication, do a rosmake and odometry_to_tf should be there.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2